# Как отсортировать данные по дате прямо в sql запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый вечер, есть вот такой вот запрос:

```
SELECT 
  comments.id, comments.imageid, comments.whoComment, 
  comments.comment, comments.date, comments.time, 
  comments.timestamp,
  maincomments.id, maincomments.imageid, maincomments.whoComment,    
  maincomments.linkToAudioComment, maincomments.date, maincomments.time,           
  maincomments.timestamp
FROM 
  comments, 
  maincomments 
WHERE 
  comments.imageid = '{$imageid}' 
AND 
  maincomments.imageid = '{$imageid}' 
LIMIT $start, $end
```

Почему именно так и зачем - неважно :)

Далее, я хочу взять `whoComment` и найти на человека, оставившего комментарий (неважно, в какой таблице, они по структуре почти похожи, но нужно именно так). Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
for ($start = 0; $start < $end; $start++) {
    if($resultComments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryToGetComments)) {
        //Берем запись. Узнаем, кто ее написал, ищем на этого юзера информацию.
        $userName = $resultComments['whoComment'];//Но из какой таблицы подставится whoComment? Нужно, чтобы просто по порядку, в зависимости от сортировки в запросе (С сортировкой тоже проблема :( )
        //Далее делаю, что хочу.
    }
}
```

Вопрос, собственно, в php коде, в комментариях. Но опять же, как отсортировать данные по дате прямо в sql запросе? Поле "Дата" есть в каждой таблице. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: 1) Используйте псевдоним для поля `SELECT ..., maincomments.whoComment AS mc_whocomment, ...FROM...` 2) какие проблемы с сортировкой? у вас её просто нет

Comment: @3per " Но опять же, как отсортировать данные по дате прямо в sql запросе? Поле "Дата" есть в каждой таблице." Нужно отсортировать записи по дате. Т.е. я могу написать так: не ...comments.whoComment...maincomments.whoComment а comments.whoComment as whocomment.....maincomments.whoComment as whocomment?

Comment: Вы неверно выбрали способ объединения таблиц. У вас CROSS JOIN, а вам нужен UNION [ALL]. И с ним обе ваши проблемы отпадут

Comment: @3per ооох, кажется веселая ночь будет. В первый раз о таком слышу :D

Comment: @IvanBlohin Да, очень похоже, что вам нужен UNION. При текущем вашем запросе если в первой таблице под условие выборки попадет 10 записей и во второй 10 записей, то на выходе вы получите 100 записей (каждая из первой _рядом_  с каждой из второй). Так что "_Почему именно так и зачем - неважно :)_" как раз очень важно. Я не могу представить задачу для которой надо было бы каждую из записей получать по многу раз

Comment: @IvanBlohin Вам видимо надо буквально `select 1 as tab,whoComment,date from comments where imageid = '{$imageid}' UNION select 2,whoComment,date from maincomments where imageid = '{$imageid}' order by tab, date`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что суть вопроса прямо противоположна заголовку (к сортировке этот вопрос не имеет никакого отношения) - то есть, вопрос не несет никакой пользы другим пользователям. И в то же время этот вопрос является следствием чудовищной архитектуры БД, и любой буквальный ответ лишь поможет автору выстрелить себе в ногу

Answer (score 3):

> Почему именно так и зачем - неважно :)

Хорошо, но скорее всего Вы получите много мусора при запросе. 
Вообще почитайте про объединения JOIN и UNION.

Если не указано явно, то порядок возвращенных данных никак не гарантируется, то есть вы можете получить любую последовательность. Для явной сортировки используйте ORDER BY, возможно указать как прямую ASC, так и обратную DESC последовательность.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY comments.date ASC
LIMIT $start, $end
```

Comment: Нет, мусора там не особо много будет :) Как сортировать я понимаю, но вопрос в том, что мне грубо говоря нужно собрать записи в кучу, а потом уже отсортировать их по полю date, которое есть в каждой таблице:)

Comment: @IvanBlohin, объединения бывают разные. Как несколько видов JOIN: [ссылка на картинку с 7 типами](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-TZk7lleQh1Y/UZoi1oaS1lI/AAAAAAAAABo/HlzwBlwuNPA/s1600/SQL+Joins1.jpg), так и UNION: [ссылка на картинку](http://www.essentialsql.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/UnionInsersectExcept.jpg)